# keep media in base URL

Tags: django, media

So, I am looking for a solution to have images through the base website URL.

Example of image url:
www.website.com/image.jpg

Where the homepage lives at the url:
www.website.com/

I am using the django python web framework, and am aware this is a peculiar, if not just bad idea, but my client has linked several hundred images to their base URL in the above format, and refuses to change the existing links.

I know this is a vague question, but I can't seem to find anything relevant. Do I just set the media url to the same as the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just configure your web server to rewrite the paths?

You could also configure it using an alternate host, assets.example.com for example and serve everything from there. Then you could rewrite all requests going at www.website.com to assets.example.com.

Comment: I must admit, I am not very good with apache, and should really work on that. I did get an idea from your answer to forward all requests (in django urls) containing .jpg/.png/.gif to the new location. bit inefficient and round about, but I think it will work. It's mostly for legacy images, all new ones will go to the correct location.